# Django attribute assignment, understanding the documentation

Tags: python, django

I see this from [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield):

```
models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Can someone explain what dose the `...,` mean in the attributes assignment?

Comment: the `...` are not actual code. It is common practice to use `...` in documentation to indicate you may add other arguments which are irrelevant to the topic discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the arguments you already have in the call.

You can think of it as *"in addition to"*.

All django model fields have certain [common options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-options), which are passed in as key/value pairs to the constructor. These are *in addition to* those:

> "***In addition to your other arguments,*** add these arguments to store
>   numbers up to 999 with a resolution of 2 decimal places."